# How to search for a part of a string in node js mongoDB

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, search

I want to know if an string contains another string.

for example I have "Harry Potter and the witch" and if someone searched for "Harry"  should get all titles including "Harry".

I'm using something like this:

```
  Book.find({title:req.params.title} , (err, books)
```

but this way user should enter the hole text.